# loopback use token in headers

Tags: javascript, token, loopback

i'm having trouble trying to recover my token's userid inside the models' remoteMethods. I used the following code :

```
User.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, user, next) {
  //...some custom token decoding
  ctx.req.body.user_id = token.user_id;
  console.log('token : ', token);
  next();
});
```

then, inside my model i used :

```
User.check = function (user_id, cb) {
  // Do stuff..
}; 


 User.remoteMethod(
    'check',
    {
      http: {path: '/check', verb: 'post'},
      returns: {arg: 'rate', type: 'object'},
      accepts: [
        {
          arg: 'user_id',
          type: 'number',
          required: true,
          description: "id of the user to check",
          http: function getUserid(ctx) {
            console.log('User.check http body : ', ctx.req.body);
            return ctx.req.body.user_id;
          }
        }
      ],
      description: ''

    }
  );
```

the problem is that my arg's function 'getUserid' gets triggered Before the 'User.beforeRemote' call.

Is that a bug ? and do you have any idea how i could make this work ?
I don't want to use an

```
arg : {http : {source : 'body'}},
```

since i only want to have the user_id arg in the remote method, and since i have to do this in about 20~30 existing methods

thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found an easier way of doing it : 
i've added my token decoding in the middleware and it works just fine, with a classic arg type number, without the http function :

```
//middleware dir :
module.exports = function (app) {
  "use strict";

  return function (req, res, next) {
    //Custom token decoding code ....
    //used req.body to show example with post requests :
    req.body.user_id = parseInt(token.user_id); 

    console.log('token : ', token);
    next();
  };
};

//remote Method declaration, without need to add a beforeRemote method : 
User.remoteMethod(
    'check',
    {
      http: {path: '/check', verb: 'post'},
      returns: {arg: 'rate', type: 'object'},
      accepts: [
        {
          arg: 'user_id',
          type: 'number',
          required: true,
          description: "id of the user to check"
        }
      ],
      description: ''
    }
  );
```